# how to use Google Shortener API with Python

Tags: python, google-api, google-url-shortener

I want to write an app to shorten url. This is my code:

```
import urllib, urllib2
import json
def goo_shorten_url(url):
    post_url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url'
    postdata = urllib.urlencode({'longUrl':url})
    headers = {'Content-Type':'application/json'}
    req = urllib2.Request(
        post_url,
        postdata,
        headers
        )
    ret = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
    return json.loads(ret)['id']
```

when I run the code to get a tiny url, it throws an exception: `urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Requests`.
What is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I tried your code and couldn't make it work either, so I wrote it with [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#make-a-request):

```
import requests
import json

def goo_shorten_url(url):
    post_url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url'
    payload = {'longUrl': url}
    headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
    r = requests.post(post_url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
    print(r.text)
```

Edit: code working with urllib:

```
def goo_shorten_url(url):
    post_url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url'
    postdata = {'longUrl':url}
    headers = {'Content-Type':'application/json'}
    req = urllib2.Request(
        post_url,
        json.dumps(postdata),
        headers
    )
    ret = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
    print(ret)
    return json.loads(ret)['id']
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.The API of urllib and urllib2 is really ugly.actually, I have written the app with requests and it works too,but why should I replace urllib.urlencode with json.dumps?

Comment: because `urlencode` passes key:value separated by & and what google API is expecting is a json like data {key:value}. [urlencode] (http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode)

Comment: in your answer I've found my solution: I was using 'params' instead of 'data' in requests.post()

Comment: @eugene you can find here how to get the key: https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/v1/getting_started#APIKey

Answer (score 5):

I know this question is old but it is high on Google.

Another thing to try is the pyshorteners library it is very simple to implement.

Here is a link:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyshorteners

Answer (score 5):

With an api key:

```
import requests
import json

def shorten_url(url):
    post_url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?key={}'.format(API_KEY)
    payload = {'longUrl': url}
    headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
    r = requests.post(post_url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
    return r.json()
```